# Erroe in script

Tags: bash

```
DBMASTERCHECK=$(ssh db0.dev.ng.keepit.com "sudo crm_mon -Afr -1|awk '/Masters:/ {print\$3}'")

echo "DB Master is: ${DBMASTERCHECK}"

STBY=$(ssh db0.dev.ng.keepit.com) sudo crm node show $(hostname) | awk '/standby/ {gsub("standby=","");print$2}'

echo "STBY is: ${STBY}"
```

Script output:

```
DB Master is: db0
Connection to db0.dev.ng.keepit.com closed.    
123: line 5: sudo crm node: command not found
STBY is:
```

It's looks like it connects to db server, but then it's do nothing

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what you're doing and without any comments on whether this is the right way to do it:

```
STBY=$(ssh db0.dev.ng.keepit.com) sudo crm node show $(hostname) | awk '/standby/ {gsub("standby=","");print$2}'
```

should probably be:

```
STBY=$(ssh db0.dev.ng.keepit.com sudo crm node show $(hostname) | awk '/standby/ {gsub("standby=","");print$2}')
```

(the closing `)` is in the wrong place).